# Is it possible to create a column underneath a content type?

Tags: column, automation-testing

So I'm trying to work on Sharepoint Automation and I'm trying to figure out on how to create a column underneath a content type.

Upon reading some documentation, from REST API, I found out that it needs to be created at the start since it's read only.

So I'm wondering, is it possible with CSOM or even REST still, and if so, is there some documentation/examples I can look up to go about this?